# Saving attachment in outlook in different folder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

I found this code on internet where you can automatically save an attachment in a certain folder:

```
   Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Temp"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there any way where I can save the attachment in different folder?

Thanks

Comment: Did you notice this line: _saveFolder = "C:\Temp"_ ? For saving from "certain folder" to different folder, change this folder name

Comment: That is VBA not VBScript. In VBScript, all variables are of type variant, so you cannot have `itm As Outlook.MailItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code hardcodes the destination folder in the `saveAttachtoDisk` sub. You can pass this information via parameter into (a variation of) this sub:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem, saveFolder As String)
  Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
  For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
      objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
      Set objAtt = Nothing
  Next
End Sub
```

and call it like this:

```
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Some\Where\Else"
saveAttachtoDisk itm, saveFolder
...
saveAttachtoDisk otheritm, "d:\why\not\here"
```

Of course, now the question is: How should these 'other folders' be determined? By user interaction? By a function applied to some Outlook/User/Main/System property?